# Facebook sdk 3.5 error "com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason"

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios6

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.5, while login i'm getting following error:

Here is the code which i'm using for facebook login

```
- (BOOL)openSession:(BOOL)allowLogin
  {  
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_photos",@"email",@"user_location",@"offline_access", nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
          allowLoginUI:allowLogin
          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session1,
                              FBSessionState state,
                              NSError *error) {[
                                  self sessionStateChanged:session1 state:state error:error];
                                     }];  
  }

 - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session  state:(FBSessionState)state  error:(NSError *)error
   {        
     switch (state) {            
       case FBSessionStateOpen:
        {

        }
       break;

       case FBSessionStateClosed:            
       case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        {
          [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];  
        }
       break;       

       default:
       break;            
      }

    if (error) {
       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"   message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];
       [alertView release];
       }
   }
```

**Error**

```
Domain=com.facebook.sdk 
Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" 
UserInfo=0x1e0a3080 
  {
    com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, 
    com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error 
    Domain=com.apple.accounts 
    Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 7.)",   
    com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1d5d69d0,
    state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed,
    loginHandler: 0x0, 
    appID: 205008289575045, 
    urlSchemeSuffix: , 
    tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x1e033950>,
    expirationDate: (null), 
    refreshDate: (null),
    attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>
   }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer.

This was creating the problem

```
 return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLogin
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session1,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {

                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session1 state:state error:error];
                                     }];
```

When i replaced the above code by this

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:allowLogin completionHandler:^(FBSession *session1, FBSessionState state, NSError *error){

    [self sessionStateChanged:session1 state:state error:error];

}];
return YES;
```

every thing started working fine.

Comment: This solved my problem as well. It would be nice to find a solution that didn't include deprecated API though.

Comment: It is depreciated in iOS 6.0

Comment: I'm not very sure why "openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:" API always gives me FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed error. But when I used "openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:" API, I'm able to login to Facebook. You saved my time @Neha, thanks a lot.

Comment: It solved my problem too. But why would this work? The other method was working for some days, then it stopped working. And both methods seem to do exactly the same...

Comment: Even worse, after this I changed back to the old method and now it works again. It seems so random...

Answer (score 1):

The user you are attempting to login with, are they registered as a Facebook developer? If your app is in sandbox mode only devs can log in.

Also make sure you've supplied your FB app info in your plist.

Comment: Yes, I have supplied the AppId in info.plist and the user is also registered as Facebook developer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to go into Settings>Facebook on your device and make sure your app "Allowed" to have access to your Facebook account. Otherwise you will get this error. Was baffled for an hour on this until I found out my App wasn't allowed to access my Facebook account...

Answer (score 1):

You are using deprecated method which is not ideal. According to facebook `@"offline_access"` is deprecated and known for login failure. remove `@"offline_access"` from your permission array then `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check:
1. Are you having developer permission to the FB app that is created. Means, if some one else created the app in their FB Account and provided the key to you, you cannot login.
2. If its in distribution mode, check that FB app is moved out from sandbox to production.

Comment: I have discovered that this error comes when the user is logged in Facebook in device's Settings otherwise it works fine. What may be the reason behind this error?

Comment: @Neha, did you try changing the sandbox mode to production in FB App?

Comment: I could not access that app on facebook as the appId is created by someone else.

Comment: @Neha, Exactly, you are now coming to the right point. You dont have developer permission. Only the person who created the Facebook App has the ability to test the facebook Login. Your FB ID has to be added as as developer by the other person. Or else ask the other person to change the status of FB app from Standalone to Production. Look at the 1st point in my answer.

Comment: That facebook appid is working fine in other apps. That means it is not related to facebook settings.

Comment: @Neha, Sorry I couldn't make any other reason for failure.